Propeller Torque Calculation
Propeller torque is given as $Torque = c_p  * ρ * (\frac{ω}{2π})^2 * d_p^5$,
where $c_p$ is the torque coefficient, ρ is the air density, ω is the angular velocity, and d is the propeller diameter.
I want to calculate the torque but I do not know the value for the torque coefficient. Is there a way to estimate it? If the propeller diameter, pitch, RPM, etc are known, can this coefficient be calculated? I read in a paper that this coefficient has a typical value of 0.006. Is this value good enough for conceptual design?

Is your propeller fixed pitch or constant speed?
If it is fixed pitch and you are designing a small UAV of some sort, then I suggest you look at the UIUC Propeller Database.  There is a tremendous amount of propeller data taken in a wind tunnel.
If you are designing a larger aircraft, in particular one with a constant speed propeller, I suggest you find a copy of Roskam's Aircraft Aerodynamics & Performance book (direct from the author).
In the Appendix of this book, they have charts taken from something called the "Red Book" (because the cover was Red).  Ok, it looks like you can find the Red Book online, so you don't need to find Roskam's book.
Ham Standard Red Book
Although a bit old, this book is an industry standard source for propeller data.  You can use it for both constant speed or fixed pitch props.
If you don't want to use one of these sources, you'll need to use a blade element code to calculate the performance of a propeller of your own design.  Such codes include JavaProp, XRotor, QProp, CCBlade, etc.

You don't need to mount a prop on the engine to determine torque.  One can mount a blade with a known drag coefficient and run the engine up to a given RPM

fuel consumption is proportional to drag torque at a given RPM.

Once you know the drag of your blade, torque is calculated as drag × the distance of center of drag from the center of the hub.
You can derive the coefficient of drag from your prop by running it at the same fuel consumption rate as your known blade.  The torque will be the same:  drag × distance to the center of the hub.
Another way is to research the engine "horsepower" output listed as torque at a given RPM.  Prop drag torque (load) = engine torque output in a steady state.
From there derive prop drag by dividing out distance to center of the hub (from prop center of drag).
Finally, one can find coefficient of drag graphs for various airfoils and angles of attack here.  0.006 seems reasonable for an estimation of coefficient of drag using your $Torque$ calculation for prop load.

I don't think you can run a mono-bladed propeller without destroying the hub

@ok, try 2 blades

@sophit, it's fine as long as you add a counter balance.
